# Создание уведомлений в центре уведомлений Windows

Tags: php, node.js, windows-10, bat, уведомления

Подскажите, как отправить уведомление в центр уведомлений Windows средствами `php` или `node.js` или `.bat`?

Как, например, это делает фреймворк **Laravel 5.3**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На PHP вряд ли есть смысл такое делать, так как это будет, скорее всего серверное приложение, а на сервере такие уведомления не нужны.

Вот, например [ссылка](https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier) на пакет для node js

```
const notifier = require('node-notifier');
// String
notifier.notify('Message');
```